# Bug with Eclipse debugger's step over

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I've found an interesting bug in eclipse's debugger for Java.

```
BookFeed feed = JAXB.unmarshal(file, BookFeed.class);
return feed;
```

If I set a breakpoint at both of those lines, then attempt to `step over` the first line, the debugger's UI hangs and I cannot do anything except pause or stop execution.

If I wait a while, pause execution, then `Resume` execution, it almost instantly moves to line two's breakpoint.

If, on the other hand, when the debugger reaches line one, I resume execution instead of using `step over`, it gets to line two and pauses quickly with no issues.

Does anyone know why this would be? Can anyone tell me a good way to get some more info about why this would be happening, so I can submit a bug with Eclipse?

Comment: You could try to step into the method to narrow down where the problem occurs.

Comment: You don't need to know why to submit a bug report. What you can do is to check if you can reproduce the bug, under what conditions etc & to create a minimal example that produces the bug so that the developers can find out why. A complex tool like eclipse has so many parts that interact that guessing the why is doomed to fail.